# The object of "I don't like people telling me what to do"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, objects

In the sentences

> I don't like people telling me what to do.
>   I'm fed up with you telling me what to do.

What are the objects of *like* and *with*? Is it "people" or "people telling me what to do" for the verb *like*?

Why can't I use a sentence just after *like* or *with*?. That is to say:

> I don't like people tell me what to do.
>   I'm fed up with you tell me what to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The object of *don't like* in

- *I don't like people telling me what to do*

is the noun phrase *people telling me what to do*. Of course it's not a single noun; it has internal structure. However, it's ambiguous. It could either mean

- *[those] people [who are] telling me what to do*,
  a complex noun phrase with a relative clause reduced by Whiz-Deletion, logically
- (∀`x`: `PEOPLE`(`x`)) `TELL` (`x`, *I*, DO (*I, What*))

or it could mean

- *people telling me what to do*, a gerund complement clause, logically
- `TELL` (*People, I,* `DO` (*I, What*))

I will assume the second meaning. In that case, the logical structure is

- `NOT` (`LIKE` (*I*, `TELL` (*People, I,* `DO` (*I, What*))))

Since *like* takes a gerund complement, `TELL` comes out as *telling* in the second clause.

The last clause is a very reduced conjunctive embedded question infinitive clause, with B-Equi indicating that the subject of `DO` is in fact identical to the indirect object of `TELL` (*I*). Some more syntactic gymnastics is required to move *what*, and add complementizers and auxiliaries all around.

As to why you **can't** say

- **I don't like you tell me what to do*,

that's because English needs more little words and has more restrictions on verbs than Chinese. *Like*, for instance, needs a *to* complementizer in front of an infinitive object,
so what you have to say is

- *I don't like you **to** tell me what to do.*

or, with the full `FOR-TO` complementizer,

- *I don't like **for** you **to** tell me what to do.*

Answer (score 1):

Both *you telling me what to do* and *your telling me what to do* are grammatical, but they have different structures: the first is a noun phrase consisting of the head *you* and the modifier *telling me what to do* (an adjectival phrase); the second is a noun phrase consisting of the head *telling me what to do* and the modifier *your*; so *telling* has a different syntactic function in the two cases.

In the case of *people*, the form without the possessive is overwhelmingly more common, but both are still grammatical.

There has been a tradition of asserting (generally on no evidence) that the first form (without the possessive) is "wrong". This seems to have arisen from assuming that English grammar must be the same as Latin grammar.

See for example the discussion [here](http://dianahacker.com/bedhandbook6e/subpages/posgerund.html) (just the first hit I found: I'm sure there are better references).

As to your final question, most verbs cannot take a whole sentence as their object: exceptions are words of uttering:

> He said "people keep telling me what to do"

where the sentence-object is generally in quotes.

Many verbs *can* take a whole sentence if it is within the scope of a complementiser:

> I hate it when people tell me what to do

but not a bare sentence.

Comment: Where did _telling me what to do_ come from, then, if it's an "adjective phrase"? The parsing seems a little odd.

Comment: @JohnLawler: yes, I think you're right. I don't suppose it can be an AP. What I was trying to capture is that (my introspection tells me) _telling_ has a participial rather than a nominal function.

Answer (score 0):

The objects are "you telling me what to do" and "people telling me what to do", not "people" or "you".

Technically, the grammar of your *initial examples* is incorrect.  It's not that you dislike the **person**; it's that you dislike their **action**. And that action is "telling me what to do".  So the phrase "telling me what to do" is a gerund, a phrase that is built on a verb but acts as a noun.

Given that, the correct forms for your initial sentences are:

> I don't like *people's* telling me what to do.
>   I'm fed up with *your* telling me what to do.

In this case, I concede that the first sentence, though grammatically correct, sounds awkward.  So I recommend re-wording it as follows:

> I don't like *when* people tell me what to do.
>   I'm fed up with *your* telling me what to do.

Your final examples are grammatically incorrect and sound awkward to a native English speaker.  The reason they are incorrect is that the words "like" and "with" require an object.  And the phrases "people tell me what to do" and "you tell me what do to" cannot act as the object because they are complete sentences in their own right.

Comment: Wrong. There is nothing "incorrect" about the initial examples, technically or otherwise. _You telling me what to do_ is a perfectly good object in English. _Your telling me what to do_ is an alternative, used by some, and insisted on by some who don't understand the grammar of their own language. See, for example [this](http://dianahacker.com/bedhandbook6e/subpages/posgerund.html)

Comment: @ColinFine Hmm.  Interesting.  I would like to point out, though, that the article you linked does refer to this as a **rule**, albeit a rule that is acceptable to ignore.  And it concludes with "Use a possessive noun or pronoun as the subject of a gerund unless doing so results in an awkward sentence".  So really a possessive noun *should* be used here (for the second sentence) because it doesn't result in an awkward sentence.

Comment: The exhortation to use a form unless it results in an awkward sentence is useless, because awkwardness is subjective. It is indeed a rule, in the sense of something that has been taught as such. However it is not a rule of English grammar.

Comment: @slidoreth Your "correct usage" is actually incorrect and quite awkward, because you're decomposing the phrases at the wrong spots. Your first mistake is caused by the ambiguity of the missing implied noun *_it_* between the *like* and the *when*. If you're explicit which would identify the remaining phrase (starting from *when*) as a compound object of the predicate *like*. 
Similarly, in the phrase *I'm fed up with your telling me what to do*, the *with* applies to the rest of the phrase not just to the word *your*. Rethink the way you're decomposing the sentences.

Comment: @ColinFine: I'm inclined to agree with Sildoreth here - and like him, I understand your link as effectively saying the same thing. In a few cases (such as our first example here, or *Basil objects to **men and women's** kissing in public* in your link), everyone would agree the possessive is "awkward", to say the least. But in most cases people either think both forms are perfectly valid and equivalent, or they think the possessive form *should* be used. Plus of course in *The teacher dislikes the child whispering to his classmate*, not using possessive potentially changes the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion comes from assuming that the construction of the two sentences is identical:

In the sentences:

> I don't like people telling me what to do.

and

> I'm fed up with you telling me what to do.

are of the form

(object verb)(gerund)

The problem is the form of gerund.  Before identifying the type of gerund let's look at a subtle point: In the first sentence "don't like" is a verb-adverb construction that can essentially be replaced by the verb "dislike". So that the sentence becomes:

> I dislike people telling me what to do.

NOTE: If the word dislike feels a bit washed down when spoken, the stress can be placed on the first syllable "dis" if there is a need to stress the "don't" in the original sentence to emphasize the emotion.

So now that we have that let's look at the respective gerunds:

> I <strike>don't like</strike> dislike people *telling me what to do*.
>
> I'm fed up with you *telling me what to do*.

In the former case it's a direct-object gerund, and in the latter there's a object of a preposition gerund (the preposition being *with* and object being *you*).

These phrases are grammatically correct.

The rest of what I was going to say about the construction of your replacements is nicely said by John Lawler :-)